# SharePoint custom field render differently in "View Properties" mode "Edit Properties" and Norman display in page

Tags: sharepoint, render, mode

I have one custom field. Here are different renderings of that page. In EditForm.aspx [through edit properties]

[image]

In DispForm.aspx [through edit properties]
  [image]

I have overrided Display Mode and Edit Mode.

But when I put a field in a page layout the page does not show any result. It just shows Mode[Display] text.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom field control that uses your custom field type, to render content in a publishing page.

[How to: Create a Custom Field Control -](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862248.aspx)
[How to: Create a Custom Field Type and Field Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417414(office.12).aspx)